# WordPress Displaying Post Content on Custom Template

Tags: wordpress, templates

I'm using a template called `single-post-{my_post_id}.php` and I'd like to understand better how to display content on it.

If I use

```
echo the_title();
echo the_content();
```

I get the title, but no content, which seems strange to me. I've read that `the_content` only works in a loop, but then how come `the title` works here? How does the template "know" the title but not the content for this particular post?

Another solution, which seems to work is:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
$content = $post->post_content;
echo $content;
```

but I'm not sure what this is doing. I'm guessing WP is "aware" from the context which post is being queried, but then how come "the_content()" isn't available?

I'm looking for info about:

- specifically how to make `the_content()` work in this context
- which approach is considered best practice
- what "overview" knowledge I seem to be lacking from what I've asked.

Any input much appreciated.

Comment: This probably isn't related to your main issue, but note that the_title() and the_content() both automatically echo the information. There's no need to `echo the_content()`, as the_content() echoes all by itself.